# sending a fax from Android with a call (not an online service)

Tags: android

Is there a  way to send a fax from an android phone using the phone (and not some fax server or service)? Is there a Java library that I could start with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like [this](http://www.java4less.com/java_fax.htm)? I've never used it - no idea if its compatible with Android. But it looks promising...

Comment: Thanks, but is there a modem available in Android?

Comment: I'd say poke around the android.telephony package: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html to see how you can open and bind to the port. Also calling the ACTION_CALL intent should trigger a call to be placed, so you may be able to get away with just initiating the call and then using that lib? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL